# Custom NumberInput widget for (subclass of) ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to create a widget that will take a numerical input for a many-to-many relationship in a field in a form. Simply put take a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` but replace the SubWidget checkbox with a `NumberInput`. On saving the form the field will create/update/delete the relation at the end of the M:M and update a column with the value provided in the NumberInput.

For some context, this is hopefully a solution to the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977220/django-modelform-field-manytomany-with-key-value-pair).

Skeleton code:

```
class ShipmentLine(models.Model):
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(Shipment, null=True, blank=True)
    checkout = models.ManyToManyField(CheckOut, null=True, blank=True)


class CheckOut(models.Model):
    volume = models.FloatField()
```

So as opposed to a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` not only will the `CheckOut` be associated, a value will be assigned to `Checkout.volume`.

I'm not having issues subclassing the field, but I do need a point in the right direction constructing the widget.

Thanks in advance

Nathan

Comment: Widgets are not supposed to perform other kind of logic except presentation, you say saving, creating etc this belongs to a Field logic not a Widget logic.
If you need to create a Field:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-model-fields/
If you need a Widget:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: @petkostas, yes I understand. it is not the saving etc I need help with, it is the creation of the label, numberinput pairs based on the list or queryset passed to the widget that I need help with.